# Realm platform create query-based Realm

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

How to create and access `Reference Realm`, a Realm that all users can access and read/write?

From docs

> Reference Realm - The master Realm file which is used in query-based synchronization. The reference Realm houses all of the data which is queried by end users. It exists only on the server. You might think of this as the database which you can create views from.

Answer (score 0):

To create reference realm

1. In Realm studio open Realms tab and click `Create new Realm` and enter realm name
2. Click on View in the top of studio and click `show system Realms`
3. Open `__admin` Realm
4. Click on `RealmFile` class and find your realm
5. Right click on the row of your Realm in `Owner` property and choose `update reference`
6. Click `select null`
7. RealmType change to `reference`

By defaul this realm is owned by admin, and app users cannot access it, so to make it shared need to follow this steps